# How to mock comosDB azure java integration AsyncDocumentClient?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, azure-cosmosdb

How to mock cosmosDB JDK integration code ? Find below my piece of code :

```
public String retrieveUserDetails() {
    ConnectionPolicy defaultPolicy = ConnectionPolicy.getDefaultPolicy();
    defaultPolicy.setUserAgentSuffix("CosmosDBJavaQuickstart");
    AsyncDocumentClient asyncClient = new AsyncDocumentClient.Builder()
            .withServiceEndpoint(AccountSettings.HOST)
            .withMasterKeyOrResourceToken(AccountSettings.MASTER_KEY)
            .withConnectionPolicy(defaultPolicy)
            .withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL)
            .build();

    String containerLink = String.format(DBS_COLLS, DB_NAME, USERROLEMAPPING);
    String sprocLink = String.format(SPROCS, containerLink, GETPROCS);
    final CountDownLatch successfulCompletionLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    String input = "{\"Email\":\""+userName+"\",\"Userid\" :\""+userId+"\"}";
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey(userId)); 
    logger.debug("input : {}", input);
    Object[] storedProcedureArgs = new Object[] { input };


    asyncClient.executeStoredProcedure(sprocLink, requestOptions, storedProcedureArgs)
            .subscribe(storedProcedureResponse -> {
                String storedProcResultAsString = storedProcedureResponse.getResponseAsString();
                    successfulCompletionLatch.countDown();
            }, error -> {
                successfulCompletionLatch.countDown();
                logger.debug("An error occurred while executing the stored procedure : actual cause ==>> {}", exceptionMsg);
            });
        return storedProcResultAsString;
}
```

Using code from https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/java/technical_deep_dive/04-authoring_stored_procedures.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It often comes down to how you write testable code than any particular mocking technology. Here I can think of following to make it testable. Since `AsyncDocumentClient` is an interface. To make your code testable, it would be good idea to create another interface for Document Client creation and inject that into your code. That way you would be able to mock of the new interface which can return a mock of `AsyncDocumentClient` while testing. Something like:

- Separate the client creation into a separate interface and it's implemmentation. For example interface `DocumentClientFactory` (with method `CreateAsyncClient` and implementation `DocumentClientFactoryImpl`. `DocumentClientFactoryImpl` would have the actual `AsyncDocumentClient` creation logic in `CreateAsyncClient` method.
- Inject DocumentClientFactory in code and call `CreateAsyncClient` instead of inline client creation.
- In test, inject the mock of `DocumentClientFactory`. The mock would return a mock `AsyncDocumentClient` having the desired behaviour required for your test.